# foreach to variable

Tags: php

I must do foreach array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => news_number
            [value] => 10
        )

)
```

and get "value" to variable $value. How i can do ?

i have :

```
foreach($this->_config as $key){

foreach($key as $value['news_number'] => $key){

echo $key;

}

}
```

but is not good i have "news_number10".

Comment: The output is "news_number10" ?

Comment: Because you're just echoing it one after the other, with no newlines or breaks or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach( $this->_config as $key => $data )
{
    echo $data['name']." is ".$data['value']."\n";
}
```

If you're looking for a specific variable in your configuration data, you could simply do this:

```
foreach( $this->_config as $key => $data )
{
    if ( $data['name'] == 'news_number' )
    {
        $myNewsNumber = $data['value'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: look one more time please i need specific variable news_number and value

Comment: Check out the edit.  That should put the value you need into $myNewsNumber.

Comment: this win because i can get more variables from settings array

Answer (score 1):

Or try that:

```
foreach( $this->_config as $data )
{
    extract($data);
    printf("%s is %s\n", $name, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do it assigning a numnber to the array?

```
foreach($this->_config as $key){

foreach($key as $value[0] => $key){

echo $key;

}

}
```

Are you intending to have just one value? then just change the array number to the array you want to use in the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$this->_config  = Array (
        0 => Array (
                'name' => "news_number",
                'value' => 10 
        ) 
);

foreach ( $this->_config as $value ) {
    echo $value ['name'], " ", $value ['value'];
}
```

Output

```
 news_number 10
```

Comment: what do you mean specific news_number to variable ?

Comment: i need only send from array to variable not need printing

Comment: value from name news_numer to variable

Comment: `$myNewsNumber = $this->_config[0]['value'];` would get you want you want